# css 3 shape correction for all browsers

Tags: css

so do all css 3 shapes not render color correctly in Firefox? I used this generator
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/
to make a triangle but I noticed when using a large value, the edges blur in Firefox so I need to use border-style: inset to make the borders perfectly sharp...however if you use border-syle:inset I also noticed the colors on Firefox become a pantone, or seriously desaturated. in Chrome the colors are fine. Is there anyway to correct the color in Firefox?

```
border-width: 0 0 351px 5527px;
border-color: transparent transparent #ff0000 transparent;
border-style:inset;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P94fm/2/

in this fiddle you can see in FF(on PC!) the color is not red, but a desaturated. In Chrome its fine. If you take off border-style: inset the color becomes perfectly red again in FF but the top border gets shadow / gradient / is not sharp

Comment: They render perfectly just as they're meant to in FireFox but Firefox renders them differently than other browsers (just as other browsers render differently from each other). There is no work around as far as I know, contact Mozilla if you'd like

Comment: im just suprised that out of all the new sites that are utilizing css3 shapes that they all either have a weird shadow in FF or dont display the correct color?! If I used border-style:inset so the border is sharp, would there be a way to make the border a saturated color with JS? not sure how border-style: inset is working to both make the border sharp on FF and desaturate color, but if I could make the color saturated with JS it would be perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is how the designers of FireFox have intentionally set. Firefox renders it differently than other browsers (like most browsers also do), in this case in a less desirable way

There is no way using CSS or javascript that I can think of which will increase the brightness of the red color without affecting other the space above the red

Although I don't know of a direct fix, you could remove the bland color by accepting a little bit of blurriness only in FireFox and have it work perfectly in the other browsers by using the following javascript

```
if(navigator.appCodeName == "Mozilla")
    document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].style.borderStyle = "solid";
```

[image: jsFiddle]

The only other work around I know of is to use a different meant to create the design you want, either an image, `<canvas>`, or SVG most likely. All of which are solid solutions to your problem, though admittedly slightly less desirable *if all browsers rendered the CSS the same way*

Comment: well right now, to split sections of the site, instead of a line its a line at a bit of an angle...Right now im using a giant png image to do this. I guess pure css option wont work across all browsers. Im curious about load times for something not purely css, so would svg be lighter than a huge png image? I know canvas can get pretty slow...I also may be able to skew a div instead of making a triangle w/ css borders..

Comment: actually it looks like you can only make a triangle with borders, not skew...I can do it with svg but I also need it to be a container with info / text and two more repeating backgrounds inside... I think canvas may be too heavy, I think I may be stuck with using a huge image for the time being

Comment: found / edited this interesting solution... wanted to post it incase someone wanted to find it or has something informational to add to it!?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hfkk7/1165/

Comment: If it's just a straight line you can simply rotate a div and absolutely position it

Comment: Thats basically what I ended up doing in the fiddle above. Faking that it is a whole box, then adding a regular box below it to fill in the space. The thing im curious about is would this be a better solution for a spacer that goes the entire width of the browser, or if using a giant png would be more browser friendly. Or if im using a huge png for a lot of sections of the site, if it would be better to use the solution above rather than a huge png for load times